# LIne chart - line color based on line direction

Tags: highcharts, line

Is there any possibility how to make a line color dependent on it's direction in line chart? I would like to have a line chart with one color for parts where the chart is ascending and a different color for the line when it is descending. I think that I have seen some example somewhere, but now I really cannot find it.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but how to do it depends very much on your data and how you are configuring highcharts with your data. Here is an example for a live chart: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/Ltdjyhyv/15/

Comment: I have just list of points. From your example it seems that I would have to add each point to the serie manually and add a zone with color for each point, isn't there any more elegant solution?

Comment: No, would not be necessary. You could do this on the load event.